# PHP add miliseconds as microtime to date

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

This is my code:

```
$d2 = new DateTime("2019-01-01 02:24:19.769002");
echo $d2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");

$tBefore = microtime(true);

// GET ANOTHER DATA

$tAfter = microtime(true);

$d2->modify('+'.($tAfter-$tBefore).' microsecond');
echo $d2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
```

But my code return wrong date for milliseconds.

I want to add seconds with milliseconds to first date and get times of `ANOTHER DATA`.

Actually if `ANOTHER DATA` take `0.100` milliseconds, my result should be `2019-01-01 02:24:19.869002`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` and `DateInterval`:

```
<?php

$d2 = new DateTime('2019-01-01 02:24:19.769002');

$tBefore = new DateTime();
// `sleep` to simulate work done between `$tBefore` and `$tAfter`
sleep(1);
$tAfter = new DateTime();

$d2->add($tBefore->diff($tAfter));

print_r($d2);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to use sleep.

Comment: @Mohammad You don't need to. the `sleep` is to simulate work done between the two times you have in your code.

Comment: Yes of course. it's my mistake. thank you

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.1, microseconds can also be easily added to DateTime using the modify method. The microsecond value must be an integer and cannot be a float. microtime (true) also delivers seconds as float and not microseconds.

```
$date = new DateTime("2019-01-01 02:24:19.769002");
$seconds = 0.100;

$intMicroseconds = intval($seconds * 1000000);
$date->modify($intMicroseconds.' microseconds');

echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
//2019-01-01 02:24:19.869002
```